# How to avoid files duplicating in Angular and Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and Typescript. So I have one moment that disturb me. All .ts file in my project have duplicates with .js. And I want to have only .ts files with no .js duplicates. How to avoid creating .js duplicates?

Comment: The .js files are probably created by your IDE, that is probably configured to automatically compile the .ts files to .js files. Check your IDE configuration.

Comment: The .js files are probably created by your IDE, that is probably configured to automatically compile the .ts files to .js files. Check your IDE configuration.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I use Atom IDE..

Comment: Just configure Atom to hide js files in source folder.

Comment: please accept answer if it's work for you for reference of visit new user.

Answer (score 0):

IDE Atom users can go with,

1. File->Settings->CoreSettings - list the patterns to ignore the files.

[image]

2. File->Settings->Packages->tree-view(search for tree-view)->Settings - check 'Hide Ignore File Names' checkbox

[image]

Now the js.map and .js files are hidden.

[image]